# Convert uri to blob in ionic 5

Tags: angular, file, ionic-framework, file-upload

I am using the file chooser plugin to pick pdf. I'm getting uri in the following format.

content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2F201215_makemyvideo_app_german_converted.pdf

```
   const buffer = await this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(uri, fileName);
   const fileBlob = new Blob([uri], { type: 'application/pdf' });
```

But I'm getting the error **input is not a directory**

How to convert uri to blob?

Answer (score 2):

This will help you.

```
  // FILE STUFF
 makeFileIntoBlob(_imagePath) {
 // INSTALL PLUGIN - cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let fileName = "";
  this.file
    .resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(_imagePath)
    .then(fileEntry => {
      let { name, nativeURL } = fileEntry;

      // get the path..
      let path = nativeURL.substring(0, nativeURL.lastIndexOf("/"));
      console.log("path", path);
      console.log("fileName", name);

      fileName = name;

      // we are provided the name, so now read the file into
      // a buffer
      return this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(path, name);
    })
    .then(buffer => {
      // get the buffer and make a blob to be saved
      let imgBlob = new Blob([buffer], {
        type: "image/jpeg"
      });
      console.log(imgBlob.type, imgBlob.size);
      resolve({
        fileName,
        imgBlob
      });
    })
    .catch(e => reject(e));
 });
}
```

This is reference [link](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/ionic4-firebase-storage)

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Comment: I use your code to convert uri to blob for pdf. I change type from image/jpeg  to application/pdf.  But blob is empty when I use: '  this.makeFileIntoBlob('file:///'+uri).then((resolve)=>{
    console.log(' makeFileIntoBlob resolve '+JSON.stringify(resolve));

    });'

Comment: I use this code to convert uri to blob for video. I change type to video/mp4. But the ```.then(buffer => {``` code is not executed.